# Accessing Non-controlled Java Applet events from a controlled application

Tags: java, applet

I'm wondering if/how one could go about accessing an applet's events from a different application. The applet which we want the events from is totally non-controllable from our code. And the application is what/where we can program. Is it possible to get the applet's events? Or even on a more far fetched note, accessing more; such as URL applet is running?

Thanks
-Dalton

Comment: Extend the applet and provide an extended interface the application can access (e.g. by socket).